# 設定されているイベントハンドラを取得する方法

Tags: javascript, jquery

要素に紐付くイベントハンドラを全て取得する方法はあるでしょうか。
たとえば、

```
<body>
  <button id="button1" onclick="alert('test1');">test</button>
  <script>
    $("#button1").click(function () {
      alert("test2");
    });
    $("#button1").click(function () {
      alert("test3");
    });
    $(document).on("click", "#button1", function () {
      alert("test4");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

のようなページの場合、#button1のボタンをクリックすると

> test1
>   test2
>   test3
>   test4

の４つのalertが表示されますが、この４つの関数を全て取得したいです。
ちなみに、

```
var onclick = $("#button1").get(0).onclick;
```

という方法では、最初の `test1` に相当する関数しか取得できませんでした。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

タグ属性の`onclick`と、`$("#button1").click()`と、`$(document).on("click", "#button1", ...)`では、イベントとしては別物になります。

`onclick`を得るには、試された方法で取得できます。これはネイティブ(？)が発火しています。

対して、`$("#button1").click()`と`$(document).on("click", "#button1", ...)`は、jQueryが発火しています。
違いは、前者がボタンそのものに対するイベントで、後者はdocumentへのイベントをselecter("#button1")で絞り込んで発火しています。

なので、それぞれ。。

```
var onclick = $("#button1").get(0).onclick;
console.log(onclick);
```

とか、

```
var events = $._data($("#button1").get(0)).events
$.each(events.click,function(){
  console.log(this.handler);
});
```

とか、

```
var events2 = $._data($(document).get(0)).events
$.each(events2.click,function(){
  if(this.selector === '#button1')
    console.log(this.handler);
});
```

とかで、取得できます。

Answer (score 2):

[デベロッパーツールでの確認方法](http://qiita.com/zaru/items/b7732ebad9b732518359)が記載されたページが有りましたので、参考までに。

以下、簡単に操作方法を記載します。

`$("#button").click()`で登録されているイベントは、コンソールから、

```
$._data($("#button1").get(0), "events");
```

と入力することで確認することができます。

同様に、`$(document).on()`で登録されているイベントは、コンソールから、

```
$._data($(document).get(0), "events");
```

と入力することで確認できます。

inputタグの属性として設定されているclickイベントは、Elementsタブから調べたい要素（今回の場合は `<button id="button1" onclick="alert('test1');">test</button>`）を選択して、EventListenersタブで確認できます。

複数イベントが表示されますが、タグの属性としてイベントを定義しているので参照先がHTMLのものが該当のものになります。

また、ElementsタブからでもjQueryのclickやonで登録されたイベントがあることは確認できますが、実際の関数の定義とは結びついていないので、実際にどのような関数が呼び出されるかを確認するためには、前述の方法でおこなうといいと思います。

Comment: 本当に他の回答と内容が同じであれば、そちらにコメントした方が分かりやすいです (ただしその前にQ&Aの投稿を通じて信用度を50まで上げる必要があります)。デベロッパーツールでの確認方法はまだ回答がないので、要点を記載しておくと回答としてより役に立つ内容になると思います。(回答はあとから[edit]できます)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。内容を編集してみました。

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます!

Answer (score 2):

参考までに、Virtual Eventというブックマークレットを使うと各要素のイベントが見られるので便利です。

- http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

ソースを読むといろいろな環境上でのイベント取得の参考にもなります。